# C++ dictionary/map with added order

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I want to have something similar to map but while iterating I want them to be in the same order as it is added.

Example

```
map.insert("one", 1);
map.insert("two", 2);
map.insert("three", 3);
```

While iterating I want the items to be like "one", ""two", "three"..By default, map doesn't provide this added order. How to get the map elements the way I have added? I want to retain the insertion order.

Anything with STL is fine or other alternative suggestions also fine.

Comment: Are you asking about retaining insertion order or having the keys ordered in the sense of the English words?

Comment: In one of my comments he also states that he needs the index access, so many of the post are wrong, due to the lack of clarity in the question

Comment: In that case, this is a dupe several times over - see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098175/a-stdmap-that-keep-track-of-the-order-of-insertion

Answer (score 5):

[A std::map that keep track of the order of insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098175/a-stdmap-that-keep-track-of-the-order-of-insertion)
this is a duplicate (thanks to neil butterworth)

You could use a map with a sorted structure parallel to it.

```
map<key, value>
vector<value*> //holds only pointers to map entries.
vector<key> //holds only map keys. Adds one indirection.
```

Comment: But I want to access by index such as 

map["one"] to return 1. Otherwise the vector needs iteration to pick find and return the elements

Comment: You can't have a vector of references, because vector elements have to be Assignable.

Comment: You can have an unordered map with iterator as the second element

Answer (score 4):

Boost mult iindex makes it possible to have a container which can be iterated over in several different orders.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Slightly modified example:

```
struct record {
    int         insertion_index;
    std::string somestring;
    int         somevalue;
    bool operator < (const record& e) const {return insertion_index < e.insertion_index;}
};

typedef multi_index_container<
    record,
    indexed_by<
        // sort by record::operator<
        ordered_unique<insertion_indexentity<record> >,        
        // sort by less<string> on somestring
        ordered_non_unique<member<record,std::string,&record::somestring> >    
    >
> record_set;
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually `std::map` by default sorts your keys using `std::less<T>` where `T` is your key's type. If you don't want the elements sorted by key, you should be using an `std::list<std::pair<K,V> >` or an `std::vector<std::pair<K,V> >` -- where `K` is your key type, and `V` is your value type, and then using `push_back` to add elements to the end of the list/vector.