# How to remove duplicate words using <map> in C++ without sorting?

Tags: c++

There is a textfile containing names:

```
Jack Sparrow
David Linch
Jack Sparrow
Umble Gamble
Lee Sion
Truman Bruman
Lee Sion
```

I have tried to remove duplicates from it using `<set>`, but the problem is that it sorts automatically. I want to do it without being sorted.

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    string name;
    set <string> nameList;

    char fileName[50];

    cout << "Please Enter file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    ifstream read(fileName);
    if(!read){
        cout << "File not found!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }


    while(read.good()){

         if(!read.eof()){

              copy(istream_iterator<string>(read),istream_iterator<string>(),inserter(nameList,nameList.end()));
    }
    }
    read.close();
        cout<<endl;
        copy(nameList.begin(),nameList.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout," "));

        cout<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Then don't use a `std::map`?

Comment: [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) and [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) are *ordered* on the key. If you want *unordered* then use [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) and [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: @Coldspeed No it doesn't - a  std::map is a tree, not a hashtable.

Comment: Also read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). Using `read.good()` is just the same.

Comment: Sounds like you want something like Python's `OrderedDict`, which keeps the order in which things get added.

Comment: Is your question that you want to remove dupes but preserve insertion order?

Comment: Here is what I think the dupe is: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2551905/2988730

Comment: I would store the names in a `std::vector` (to preserve the order) and additionally registering their indices in a `std::set` whereby using a special comparator which accesses the vector and considers the names at the resp. indices.

Comment: You could use the set just to check if the value was seen before and use a vector for actual storage of the result.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, (in opposition to at least 4 other guys) I don't get it. AFAIK, neither `std::unordered_set` nor `std::unordered_map` preserve the insertion order. What am I missing?

Comment: @Scheff The OP doesn't actually say anything about preserving insertion order, just that the contents should not be sorted (ordered).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So, you tried to teach something else (e.g. how important it is to clearly specify the intention). Somehow, I was expecting such an answer. But, you are right: "Preserving order" was my own interpretation...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will try using unordered_set, but I am not sure whether task asking me this

Comment: How to read from text file into unordered_set?

Comment: @Scheff I don't wanna use vector dude

Comment: Actually, it could be very simple: Use a `std::set<std::string>` for book-keeping (i.e. to detect whether a name is a duplicate). If a name is inserted the 1st time then output it otherwise discard it. Did your assignment require that it _must_ be stored somewhere or that input and output may not happen "interleaved"?

Comment: And, now the highest-voted comment of Some programmer dude makes somehow sense to me. Iff the assignment says that it may not be sorted (whyever it shouldn't) then just use an `std::unorder_set` instead. The APIs of `std::set<>` and `std::unordered_set<>` are (as for every container template) quite similar.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks man