# Make Map Key Sorted According To Insert Sequence

Tags: c++, stl

Without help from additional container (like vector), is it possible that I can make map's key sorted same sequence as insertion sequence?

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  map<const char*, int> m;
  m["c"] = 2;
  m["b"] = 2;
  m["a"] = 2;
  m["d"] = 2;


  for (map<const char*, int>::iterator begin = m.begin(); begin != m.end(); begin++) {
      // How can I get the loop sequence same as my insert sequence.
      // c, b, a, d
      std::cout << begin->first << std::endl;
  }

  getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  A `std::map` is a sorted container; the insertion order is not maintained.  There are a number of solutions using a second container to maintain insertion order [in response to another, related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098175/a-stdmap-that-keep-track-of-the-order-of-insertion).

That said, you should use `std::string` as your key.  Using a `const char*` as a map key is A Bad Idea:  it makes it near impossible to access or search for an element by its key because only the pointers will be compared, not the strings themselves.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like a duplicated question.

Answer (score 4):

No. `std::map<Key, Data, Compare, Alloc>` is sorted according to the third template parameter `Compare`, which defaults to `std::less<Key>`. If you want insert sequence you can use `std::list<std::pair<Key, Data> >`.

#### Edit:

As was pointed out, any sequential STL container would do: `vector`, `deque`, `list`, or in this particular case event `string`. You would have to decide on the merits of each.

Comment: Iiiirrk. And yet another developer recommends a `list`. Neil will bash you on the head if he ever hears of this. Hint: you'd better recommend a `vector` or a `deque`, there is absolutely no requirement here that would suggest using a `list` is ever remotely useful.

Comment: There's no requirement to use vector either. At some point one has to learn to make one's own decisions and not just listen to Neil.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a boost::multi_index container instead of a std::map.  You can put both an ordered map index and an unordered sequential index on your container.