# QMap but without sorting by key

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures, qmap

I need structure like QMap but without sorting on keys, so if I insert item there first I can count that this item will be before all others. And insert pair before or after specified element. Does Qt have such?

Comment: @jrok no, I need to store pair, key and value

Comment: Well, use a `QPair` then. But after your edit, I see you can't use a queue - you can't insert randomly in a queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QMap` is implemented as a tree, which means that the insertion order does **not** matter. It appears that you are looking for a **queue**. However, if you need a container which can be iterated in both insertion order and at the same time accessed through a specific key, then Qt has no such structure for you.

These could help you:

- [A std::map that keep track of the order of insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098175/a-stdmap-that-keep-track-of-the-order-of-insertion)
- [Make Map Key Sorted According To Insert Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664837/make-map-key-sorted-according-to-insert-sequence)

Answer (score 2):

I use a

```
QList<QPair<key,value>>
```

to achieve this. But look up consumes more time as you will need to loop through the QList and use the QPair.first to look for the item you want.

edit: if you dont need it to interact with other API alot, you can use QVector to replace QList which is faster according to Qt official

Comment: for example I want to store a list of students' maths score sorted by the way I insert them. First I would construct a QPair<student_name, score> for every student, then I insert them in a QList. When I need the "queue" ability of it, I can use a for loop and loop through the QList, when I need the "hash" ability, I will loop through the QList and look at the QPair.first => student_name, if matches, returns the QPair.second=>score

Comment: This doesn't provide features e.g. insert/lookup by key, of course, but it does allow for the preservation of k/v pairs in a specific order.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I'm sharing the solution I used

```
QMap<QString,int> OldStudentList;
OldStudentList["Dantesc"]     = 8;
OldStudentList["Constantin"]  = 10;
OldStudentList["Abraham"]     = 15;
```

The "QMap" listing gave this :
"Abraham" 15
"Constantin" 10
"Dantesc" 8

Rather than using a QMap I therefore used a structure with a QList of this structure

```
struct Student
{
  QString name;
  int note;
};

QList<Student> studentList;

Student currentPers;

currentPers.name = "Dantesc";
currentPers.note = 8;
studentList.append(currentPers);

currentPers.name = "Constantin";
currentPers.note = 10;
studentList.append(currentPers);

currentPers.name = "Abraham";
currentPers.note = 15;
studentList.append(currentPers);

for(int i=0;i<studentList.size();i++){ qDebug() << studentList[i].name << studentList[i].note; }
```

This listing give this :
"Dantesc" 8
"Constantin" 10
"Abraham" 15
**I keep the order of the data entered**

Hope this solution can help someone