# a data structure between multimap and vector

Tags: c++, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A std::map that keep track of the order of insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098175/a-stdmap-that-keep-track-of-the-order-of-insertion)

I'm looking for a STL container that works like std::multimap but i can access the members in order of insertion like vector.

for example:

```
  multimap<char,int> mymultimap;
  multimap<char,int>::iterator it;

  mymultimap.insert ( pair<char,int>('a',100) );
  mymultimap.insert ( pair<char,int>('z',150) ); 
  mymultimap.insert ( pair<char,int>('b',75) );
  mymultimap.insert ( pair<char,int>('a',75) );

  for ( it=mymultimap.begin() ; it != mymultimap.end(); it++ )
    cout << (*it).first << " => " << (*it).second << endl;
```

output:

a => 100

a => 75

b => 75

z => 150

expected output:

a => 100

z => 150

b => 75

a => 75

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A std::map that keep track of the order of insertion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098175/a-stdmap-that-keep-track-of-the-order-of-insertion) (Just don't use unique for multi_map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boost libraries have a flexible multiple index container that does what you want and more: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

You can construct multi_index containers that can be accessed sequentially but also allow O(log(N)) fast lookup. The syntax is a little opaque to start off with, but once you get something working it's a worthwhile investment as the implementation will have been thoroughly tested by the boost guys and a large number of general users.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::vector<std::pair<char,int> >` for this. Also, you can use `std::make_pair` function to create a pair. Here is the sample code:

```
vector<pair<char,int> > v;
    vector<pair<char,int> >::iterator it;

  v.push_back ( make_pair('a',100) );
  v.push_back ( make_pair('z',150) ); 
  v.push_back ( make_pair('b',75) );
  v.push_back ( make_pair('a',75) );

  for ( it=v.begin() ; it != v.end(); it++ )
    cout << (*it).first << " => " << (*it).second << endl;
```

Comment: look up complexity of vector is O(n), i need a faster solution.

Comment: @al bid complexity of which operation?  If you have other requirements, you should list them in your question as well.

Comment: dear Nick,
i need all feature of Multimap + sequential access in order of insertion

Answer (score 0):

Other than a `std::vector<std::pair<char,int> >` as already suggested, maybe [boost::bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) would be a good solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `multimap` with `list`.

Below is a container that do what you want. Objects are stored in a `multimap` and additional `list` stores multimap iterators (they stay valid as long as pointed element is in the container). All operations have the same complexity like in `multimap` except `erase` methods which are *O(n*m)* where *n* is number of all elements and *m* is number of elements removed.

```
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

template <class Key, class T>
class my_map : public std::multimap<Key, T> {
public:
    typedef typename std::multimap<Key, T> multimap_type;

    typedef typename multimap_type::key_type   key_type;
    typedef typename multimap_type::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename multimap_type::size_type  size_type;
    typedef typename multimap_type::iterator   iterator;

    struct order_iterator : std::list<typename multimap_type::iterator>::iterator {
        typedef typename std::list<typename multimap_type::iterator>::iterator iterator_t;

        order_iterator() {}
        order_iterator(const iterator_t &iterator) : iterator_t(iterator) { }

        const std::pair<const Key, T>& operator *  () const { return ***(const iterator_t*)this; }
              std::pair<const Key, T>& operator *  ()       { return ***(      iterator_t*)this; }
        const std::pair<const Key, T>* operator -> () const { return &**this; }
              std::pair<const Key, T>* operator -> ()       { return &**this; }
    };

private:
    std::list<typename multimap_type::iterator> list;
    multimap_type *base() { return this; }

public:
    order_iterator order_begin() { return this->list.begin(); }
    order_iterator order_end() { return this->list.end(); }

    iterator insert(const value_type& x)
    {
        iterator ret = this->base()->insert(x);
        this->list.push_back(ret);
        return ret;
    }

    iterator insert(iterator position, const value_type& x)
    {
        iterator ret = this->base()->insert(position, x);
        this->list.push_back(ret);
        return ret;
    }

    template <class InputIterator>
    void insert(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
    {
        while (last != first) this->insert(first++);
    }

    void erase(iterator first, iterator last)
    {
        if (first == this->end()) return;

        for (iterator it = first; it != last; ++it) {
            this->list.erase(std::find(this->list.begin(), this->list.end(), it));
        }
    }

    void erase(iterator position)
    {
        iterator last = position;
        this->erase(position, ++last);
    }

    size_type erase (const key_type& x)
    {
        iterator range_begin = this->lower_bound(x);
        if (range_begin == this->end()) return 0;

        size_type ret = 0;
        iterator range_end = range_begin;
        do range_end++, ret++; while (range_end != this->end() && range_end->first == x);

        this->base()->erase(range_begin, range_end);
        for (; range_begin != range_end; range_begin++) {
            this->list.erase(std::find(this->list.begin(), this->list.end(), range_begin));
        }

        return ret;
    }

    void clear()
    {
        this->list.clear();
        this->base()->clear();
    }
};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

my_map<char,int> mymultimap;

void dump()
{
    cout << "by insert:\n";
    for (
        my_map<char,int>::order_iterator it = mymultimap.order_begin();
        it != mymultimap.order_end();
        it++
    ) {
        cout << (*it).first << " => " << (*it).second << endl;
    }

    cout << "by key:\n";
    for (
        my_map<char,int>::iterator it = mymultimap.begin();
        it != mymultimap.end();
        it++
    ) {
        cout << (*it).first << " => " << (*it).second << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    mymultimap.insert(make_pair('a',100));
    mymultimap.insert(make_pair('z',150));
    mymultimap.insert(make_pair('b',75));
    mymultimap.insert(make_pair('a',75));
    dump();

    mymultimap.erase('a');
    dump();
}
```

If iterating elements in insertion order is more intensively used then lookup by a key then it would be more optimal to "mirror" the idea: store key/value pairs in a `list` (so we can iterate in insertion order) and have additional `multiset` containing iterators to `list` elements (for by-key-lookup purposes).