# Preserving insertion order on a std::set or std::unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl, set

Before marking this as duplicate, I have been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098175/a-stdmap-that-keep-track-of-the-order-of-insertion), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942783/need-stl-set-in-insertion-order), and [here, a duplicate of the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278580/stl-container-that-preserves-order-of-insertion-but-allows-no-duplicates).

I'm aware of `boost::multi_index`, and use an environment where I lack it, and that a `std::unordered_set` is not bound to store elements in a deterministic insertion order.

I find the concept of using two containers, say an additional `std::vector` as uncouth.

What I *would love* is a solution involving a comparator that I can use in a `std::set`'s template parameters (clarification, this could be a trivial functor struct, containing a `bool operator()()` overload, a regular function, or a lambda). Is it possible?

#### Addenda

1. Initialization must occur through a std:: container's begin iterator/end iterator constructor, such as in this snippet.

   ```
   std::string str; cin >> str;
   std::set<char>(str.begin(), str.end());
   ```
2. Also, another interesting use-case would be to create a dumb hash wrapping functor that allows insertion order to be pushed in to a `std::unordered_set`'s template parameter.

Comment: What's your question? (Make your question *self-contained*, and you can tell whether something is a question by the presence of a question mark. Everything else is a rant, or a tweet.)

Comment: *Is it possible?* I do admit that I ended up sounding like that, so I wanted to clarify. Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Context -- I still have no idea what you want to do.

Comment: @KerrekSB The heading, please.

Comment: Stop using containers in a way they were not designed to work. If you want a set sorted in insertion order then why not make your *own* structure?

Comment: Because it is cumbersome and probably a lambda would work here. I'm lazy af, that's all :P Also AFAIK a `std::set` allows exactly that, so why not use a container how I like it if I can configure its behavior?

Comment: If (insertion-) order matters don't use unordered containers.Use one of the ordered ones instead. `std::vector` is a pretty decent default.

Comment: No - headings are for indexing a post on the questions list. Your question body needs to be self-contained separately. Say *in your question* what you mean to ask, don't expect people to scavenge around to piece together *your* question.

Comment: @nwp exactly! Still, need duplicate removal and insertion order. No `std::vectors`, sorry.

Comment: @mushi: An *unsorted* vector would work, at the expense of search time.

Comment: @KerrekSB yeah, that's one way I'd do it, but duplication removal.

Comment: @mushi: no no, you still scan for duplicates on insertion, but the scan has to be a linear search (since the range isn't sorted). No duplicates.

Comment: @KerrekSB maybe. Well it works, suffice to say. Somehow doesn't strike as elegant. Still, +1 to you.

Comment: Or just reimplement multiindex. Not really hard, you just need two separate data structures that you keep in sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly have a lambda expression as the set's template parameter, because a lambda expression is a value, and the set's template parameter is a type. The obvious correction of the question, whether a construction using a lambda and `decltype` can work, leads to the interesting problem that a lambda expression denotes a *unique* type (a "closure type"), so you can never make two separate lambda expressions of the same closure type.*

However, in a more abstract sense what you want can be achieved in a local context using template argument deduction, for example:

```
template <typename F>
int f(int* first, int* last, F comp)
{
    std::set<int, F> s(comp);
    while (first != last) s.insert(*first++);
    ...
}
```

Now you can call `f` with a lambda expression as the argument, thus effectively "using a lambda as the set's comparator". Or, for a simpler example, you could just have a named variable for the lambda (putting all the template deduction into a single `auto`:

```
auto comp = [](...) { ... };
std::set<int, decltype(comp)> s(comp);
```

<sub>*) There is a proposal to allow lambdas in unevaluated contexts to address this point, but its outlook is uncertain. It has interesting side effects like making closure types affect name mangling.</sub>

Comment: It's obvious I'll need a `decltype()` to get to the lambda's type in the template parameter list. Just a one-shot lambda will do. The answer isn't valid for this question. Still, the effort is commendable, so I'd upvote it.

Comment: It' can't be "one-shot" if you would need the lambda at least twice, though! Closure types aren't default-constructible. (There's another proposal to address that, which actually has good chances for C++20.)

Comment: I assume I won't need it twice. I could say this lambda exists within `main()`, so it may not *need* to be a lambda. Thanks for highlighting this point, I've updated my question.

Comment: It isn't the use case I'm looking for sir ._.

Comment: (Yes, you could say `auto f = []...; set<int, decltype(f)> s(f);`; that's a simpler variant on the "deduction" I used in my example.)

Comment: EXACTLY. THANK YOU. Jk thank goodness we're on the same page `:)

Comment: Right :-) But that's not a lambda in the set -- now that's a named variable of closure type. The lambda expression now appears separately, unrelated to the set. The deeper point here is that you *cannot* have such kinds of sets in public interfaces, for example.

Comment: Yeah, that's something I have to consider.

Answer (score 1):

An adt that preserves the order of insertion is an std::vector.
You can just as easily wrap it like this to get an std::set-like behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template < typename T >
class VectorSet : public vector<T> {
public:
    using iterator = typename vector<T>::iterator;
    using value_type = typename vector<T>::value_type;

    pair<iterator, bool> insert (const value_type& val) {
        auto it = ::find(this->begin(), this->end(), val);
        if (it == this->end())
            it = ::vector<T>::insert(this->end(), val);

        return pair<iterator, bool>(it, true);
    }
};

int main()
{
    VectorSet<int> my;
    my.insert(1);
    my.insert(4);
    my.insert(3);
    my.insert(4);

    for (auto & v : my) {
        cout << v << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing `std::find`?

Comment: Plus it's too verbose. Not to mention, oh my, extending a std:: container :O

Comment: @mushi, Extending a container is a debatable issue, I actually think it is very artistic :)

Comment: Well, HackedStack and HackedQueue sure crack me up whenever I see them

Comment: LOL :) Definitely! But does pro::vector seems that bad? ;]

Comment: Well, not virtually. xD

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, unless you use additional indexes. Two approaches:

### 1. using an explicit index

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e11324b73f5a399)</kbd>**

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

string read_word() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    return str;
}

int main() {
    using Ref = std::reference_wrapper<char const>;

    auto const str = read_word();
    std::cout << "Word: "   << str << "\n";

    auto v = [&]() -> vector<Ref> {
        set<Ref> u(str.begin(), str.end());
        return {u.begin(), u.end()};
    }();

    std::cout << "Unique: " << string(v.begin(), v.end()) << "\n";

    auto pos = [str](char ch) { return str.find(ch); };
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [pos](auto& a, auto& b) { return pos(a) < pos(b); });

    std::cout << "Insertion: " << string(v.begin(), v.end()) << "\n";
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
Word: pineapple
Unique: aeilnp
Insertion: pineal
```

### 2. using Boost Multi-Index

Same deal

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/719f48f5b97e66fe)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index; 

using Index = bmi::multi_index_container<char, 
      bmi::indexed_by<
          bmi::sequenced<>,
          bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<struct unique>, bmi::identity<char> >
      > > ;

#include <iostream>

std::string read_word() {
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;
    return str;
}

int main() {

    auto const str = read_word();
    std::cout << "Word: "   << str << "\n";

    Index idx(str.begin(), str.end());

    std::cout << "Insertion: " << std::string(idx.begin(), idx.end()) << "\n";

    auto& u = idx.get<unique>();
    std::cout << "Unique: " << std::string(u.begin(), u.end()) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Word: pineapple
Insertion: pineal
Unique: aeilnp
```

Comment: I'd say the boost multi-index approach is basically what you wanted. Note that you can achieve this particular mix using an intrusive set over another container too.

Answer (score 0):

I thought a weird solution (though not one involving any sets) could be to use a `std::map` of the element type and `std::time_point` as the key type. That will ensure insertion order if not anything at all.

Comment: Except then it's just a very very inefficient vector. How will you still look up by the original key

Comment: A red-black implemented map wouldn't become a one dimensional vector, and AFAIR when I had made the OP I thought I wouldn't need random access, so simple iteration was probably what I was aiming for, in which case I wouldn't need to look up using the `std::time_point` key.

Comment: Indeed. It will not become a one dimensional vector, and that's exactly what makes it wasteful, because you didn't need the fancy features. A map is orders of magnitudes more complicated/ expensive and doesn't give you anything in terms of traversal that a vector wouldn't

Comment: Except requiring an explicit call to `std::sort`. Otherwise, I like the `std::vector` approach. It's probably more efficient.

Comment: huh. No need to sort a vector just to preserve insertion order

Comment: have you ever considered https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html and similar? (It didn't fit the question but it seems you're really looking for something else)

Comment: That was pretty enlightening. Of course, when I had made the post I hadn't considered it. Boost covers all the use-cases all too well. :p