# How are std::map's ordered

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to understand the ordering in a std::map.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

**Internally, the elements in a map are always sorted by its key following a specific strict weak ordering criterion indicated by its internal comparison object (of type Compare).**

If I do this:

```
   myMap["two"] = 2;
   myMap["three"] = 3;
   myMap["one"] = 1;
```

and then iterate over `myMap`, printing out the value as I go, what will the output be?

I'm looking for a container where the elements are in the order that they are added. In this case I'd expect the output 2, 3, 1 for iteration.

Comment: What you're looking for is probably a `vector` of `pair`s

Comment: Well no `std::map` keeps the elements ordered by key (in your case `string` lexicographic ordering) to allow fast (logarithmic) time access by key. It doesn't retain insersion order.

Comment: This may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098175/a-stdmap-that-keep-track-of-the-order-of-insertion

Comment: "If I do this and then iterate over myMap, printing out the value as I go, what will the output be?" -- have you considered *trying* it and seeing what happens? What's the worst that could happen?

Comment: `unordered_set` has good performance and *in my experience* iterates in *reverse* insertion order, but that is probably implementation specific. Just use `vector< pair<string, int> >` if you don't need fast access by key.

Comment: @Antoine you can't make any assumptions about the order of iteration of an `unordered_set`.

Answer (score 2):

A vector/FIFO queue would simply do what you desire, without you needing to worry about how the map stores the objects internally OR bloating your code with a data structure that is more complicated for the job at hand.

std::queue is a FIFO queue

Answer (score 1):

The order in your example depends on the definition of your `std::map`. Note that [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is a template with four template parameters:

```
std::map< Key, Value, Compare, Allocator >
```

where the third one is important for the order. Given that you have `std::map< std::string, int >`, the default for the third parameter `Compare` is `std::less< Key >`, which is `std::less< std::string >`, which in turn means that the keys (which are of type `std::string`) are compared with `<`. Hence the order in your case would be `1, 3, 2` because `std::string("one") < std::string("three")` and `std::string("three") < std::string("two")`.

As already pointed out by others, you are looking for a different container which models a [sequence container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).