# STL map to find the first non repeatable character

Tags: c++, stl

I have written a small C++ program to keep a count of the alphabets.
I am using stl map for the same,

Interestingly, i am not getting the list as it appeared in the input.
For example for the word TESTER, my program should give

```
T  2
E  2
S  1
R  1
```

But its giving,

```
E       2
R       1
S       1
T       2
```

change in the position of the alphabets,

I want the o/p of the alphabets as it appeared in the input. Please help me if i am missing anything.Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *str = "TESTER";
    map<char,int> checkmap;
    map<char,int>::iterator p;
    int i;
    while( *str != '\0' )
    {
        p = checkmap.find(*str);
        i = p->second;
        if(p == checkmap.end())
        {
            checkmap.insert(std::make_pair(*str,++i));
        }
        else
        {
            p->second = ++(p->second);
        }
    str++;
    }
    for(p=checkmap.begin(); p!=checkmap.end(); p++)
    {
        /*if(p->second == 1)
        {
            cout<<(*p).first<<endl;
        }*/
        cout<<p->first<<"\t"<<p->second<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [A std::map that keep track of the order of insertion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098175/a-stdmap-that-keep-track-of-the-order-of-insertion)

Comment: You can use an array instead of a map since characters are considered as integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is shown an approach how it can be done

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    const char *str = "TESTER";

    auto order = [&]( char c1, char c2 )
    {
        return ( std::strchr( str, c1 ) < std::strchr( str, c2 ) );
    };

    std::map<char, int, decltype( order )> m( order );

    for ( const char *p = str; *p; ++p ) ++m[*p];

    for ( const auto &p : m ) std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
T 2
E 2
S 1
R 1
```

Comment: @juanchopanza  I simply repeated my old answer to some other similar question. The only difference is that there was used an std:;string object instead of the string literal. So instead of standard function strchr I used member function find.:)

Comment: It's somewhat of a pity that the `order` lambda is so expensive (O(N) per invocation).

Comment: @MSalters  What can you suggest?

Comment: `std::strchr(str,c)` can be memoized. If I would have had a simple suggestion how to do that, I'd offer it. But I'm afraid you're going to need a `size_t[UCHAR_MAX]` and that in turn means your lambda has to become a stateful functor.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing that `std::map` has its own internal ordering, which is completely independent of the order in which elements are added. As you can see from your example, it is ordered alphabetically. This is in increasing order of the value of the `char` key.

Also note that your map manipulations are overly complex. All you need to do is

```
char *str = "TESTER";
map<char,int> checkmap;

while( *str != '\0' )
{
    checkmap[*str]++;
    ++str;
}
```

The `while` can be collapsed further if you're into that kind of thing:

```
while( *str != '\0' ) checkmap[*str++]++;
```

For the general problem of mapping values while maintaining insertion order, see [A std::map that keep track of the order of insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098175/a-stdmap-that-keep-track-of-the-order-of-insertion)

Comment: Thanks @juanchopanza                                                                               Is there any way i can get the alphabets as it appeared in the input?

Comment: @Rndp13 Not trivially. You could push elements into a vector of `pair<char, int>`, and only push new elements if the pair's first element does not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to keep track of the order in which elements are added to map. To get the same order it would be advisable to use `std::vector<std::char, int>` and then update the same.