# Assign key value in map - special strings(% and $)

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary

I have below map code in C++-

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> vals;
vals["%"] = "PERCENT";
vals["$"] = "DOLLAR";
vals["="] = "EQUAL";
```

With above code lines I expect % will be at index 0 and $ at index 1. But when I compile and debug I always find $ at index 0 and % at index 1.

anybody has any idea why this is happening? maintaining sequence is must for me , any suggestion how can I get rid of it.

Comment: What do you mean by "index 0"?  Do you mean `vals.begin()` is `$`?

Comment: Yes vals.begin() is $

Comment: `std::map` must guaranty O(log n) access by key, so usually it is realized with the rb-tree. If you need same functionality without key access, but keeping order you can use `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>`

Comment: On a side note, you can use `Uniform Initialization` (introduced by C++11) by writting `std::map<std::string, std::string> vals = { {"%", "PERCENT"},  {"$", "DOLLAR"}, {"=", "EQUAL"} };`

Answer (score 3):

That's because `std::map` sorts its content. The order of insertion doesn't matter. Here, it will sort on alphabetical order.(because the key value is `std::string`) Because `$` has a lower value than `%` this means that `$ == vals.begin()`. This is also why user-defined types used as keys in a `map` require their `operator<` to be overloaded.

Comment: is there anyway I can maintain order of insertion?

Comment: @user987316 Maintaining order of insertion is not something `map` cares about. Try `std::vector`.

Comment: insert elements into std::list<std::string> and have a std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string>::const_iterator>> for fast lookup ?

Comment: I see this post: [A std::map That Keeps Order of Insertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098175/a-stdmap-that-keep-track-of-the-order-of-insertion).

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'natural' standard dictionary container that preserves the order of insertion. Neither `std::map` nor `std::unordered_map` will do this. If you need to preserve the order of insertions, you need to use a container which can do this and insert `std::pair<your_key_type, your_value_type>`.

The obvious drawback of that is that uniqueness of your keys will no longer be enforced automatically, so that is something you will have to take care about - with huge performance penalty.

The 3 standard containers which will suit you are `std::vector`, `std::deque` and `std::list`, and the most performant one usually is the `std::vector`.

There are also third-party libraries (boost, for example) which have some containers which might suit you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't think of the subscript operator as an array index in this case. For std::map operator is overloaded where the contents of [] is the templated type of your key. In this case you're using a string to string map and so you put strings inside of []. As far as how the contents are sorted when you iterate over the contents, I believe this STL implementation specific. However, looking at the link [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) you will see that you can optionally provide a comparitor that can override the default sort.

I think you'd have a hard time getting to a insertion order iteration, but that isn't the point of a map.