# Replacing mapped vector with boost multi_index reasonable?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, multi-index, boost-multi-index

In my application I'm storing a huge(!) container: A vector of vectors.
Each of the vectors has a unique name and I use a map to store the index
to the vector for further access. Storing the data in vectors is needed
in my application as I have to do a lot of processing and therefore need
fast access to the elements in it.

Unfortunately std::map doesn't care for the insertion order which is
important in my use case and I came across this topic:

[A std::map that keep track of the order of insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098175/a-stdmap-that-keep-track-of-the-order-of-insertion)

Unfortunately the proposed solution is not exactly what I need and I now wonder:

- Is it possible to make boost_multi_index use vectors to store the data?
- Is it reasonable at all (in my case) to replace vector/map usage with boost multi_index or
- Use something like bimap or
- Is there a more elegant way for "my problem"?

Sample code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using payload_t = std::vector<uint32_t>;
using container_t = std::vector<payload_t>;
using container_map_t = std::map<std::string, size_t>;
using connectionMask_t = std::map<std::string, uint32_t>;

int main()
{
    container_t container;
    container_map_t container_map;

    // Store 1st payload
    container.push_back(std::move(payload_t{1,2,3}));
    container_map["One"] = container.size() - 1;

    // Store 2nd payload
    container.push_back(std::move(payload_t{4,5,6,7}));
    container_map["Two"] = container.size() - 1;

    // Store 3rd payload
    container.push_back(std::move(payload_t{8,9}));
    container_map["Three"] = container.size() - 1;

    // Assign unique mask to each layer (name)
    connectionMask_t masks;
    for (auto const&[name, data] : container_map)
    {
        // Assign mask to each layer
        masks[name] = 1UL << masks.size();
    }

    // Iterating vector access
    for (auto& outer : container)
        for (auto& inner : outer)
            std::cout << inner;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    // Direct vector access
    for (auto& inner : container[1])
        std::cout << inner;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    // Access via name
    for (auto& inner : container.at(container_map.at("Two")))
        std::cout << inner;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    // Iterating access via map; order not preserved
    for (auto& [key, vec] : container_map)
    {
        std::cout << key << ": ";
        for (auto& inner : container[vec])
            std::cout << inner;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The top voted answer in the question you linked showed how to use `boost::multi_index`. You just exchange `int i` for `payload_t whatever` in `value_t`

Comment: Data is stored as map? I need vectors.

Comment: The inner vectors are stored in a container with equivalent access complexity to `std::vector`. It also maintains an index to lookup by name, similar to your `container_map_t`, meaning you don't have to write code to keep them in sync

Comment: The `random_access` index ensures vector-like storage

Comment: Why don't you store the reference to the `vector` inside the `map`? Also why do you use `map` instead of `unordered_map`?

Comment: Not really an issue but `container.push_back(std::move(payload_t{1,2,3}));` can be simplified to `container.push_back(payload_t{1,2,3});` or even `container.push_back({1,2,3});`.  The `std::move` is not needed as you already have an rvalue.  The type is not needed as well since `push_pack` takes the element type.

Comment: Besides of "I do a lot of processing and need fast access to the elements" you gave no other information about your problem. If you can give more info what do you want to solve, someone may come with the better data structure.

Comment: The data in the inner vector are boost::geometry polygons.

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko Using unordered_map seems reasonable. But storing the references might be problematic if the outer vector needs reallocation!?

Comment: @fhw72 Right, after the reallocation pointers to stored elements become invalid. In this case you may want to use `std::deque`. It provides a random access at `O(1)` and it does not reallocate the objects upon insertion to the begin/end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Is it possible to make boost_multi_index use vectors to store the data?

No. All the containers are implemented on node-based storage so iterator/reference stability is guaranteed.

> - Is it reasonable at all (in my case) to replace vector/map usage with boost multi_index [or]

It seems so, but see below.

> - Use something like bimap

It's unclear to me how it will fill any gap.

> - Is there a more elegant way for "my problem"?

Perhaps. Simplest wins, IMO:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/918769917e168782)**

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

#include <fmt/ranges.h>

using payload_t = std::vector<uint32_t>;
using map_t     = std::map<std::string, payload_t>;
using entry_t   = map_t::value_type;
using ref_t     = std::reference_wrapper<entry_t>;

int main() {
    map_t              container;
    std::vector<ref_t> index;

    auto insert = [&](std::string name, payload_t element) {
        auto [it, ok] = container.emplace(std::move(name), std::move(element));
        if (ok)
            index.push_back(*it);
        else
            assert(false); // TODO decide on how to behave
    };

    for (auto&& [name, data] : { std::tuple //
             {"One", payload_t{1, 2, 3}},
             {"Two", payload_t{4, 5, 6, 7}},
             {"Three", payload_t{8, 9}},
         })
    {
        insert(std::move(name), data);
    }

    fmt::print("All (order not preserved): {}\n", container);

    for (int i = 0; entry_t& inner : index)
        fmt::print("At #{}, {}: {}\n", i++, inner.first, inner.second);

    fmt::print("Access via name: {}\n", container.at("Two"));
}
```

Printing

```
All (order not preserved): {"One": [1, 2, 3], "Three": [8, 9], "Two": [4, 5, 6, 7]}
At #0, One: [1, 2, 3]
At #1, Two: [4, 5, 6, 7]
At #2, Three: [8, 9]
Access via name: [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

### From Here

Sprinkle in what you need to taste:

- Boost Container

  - stable vector (for ... stability)
  - flat map (for locality of reference and reducing allocations)
  - small_vector (e.g. for the payloads. In the example they are very samll, `small_vector` or even `static_vector` will be a huge performance improvement)
- Boost Interprocess

  To put all of this in shared memory/memory mapped files. This will allow you to deal with data structures way bigger than available RAM and also persisting across runs

Comment: Here's what the multi_index_container approach looks like to me, you didn't really say what you don't like (I'm assuming the node-based allocations): https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aeeb7d443373492d

Comment: Great suggestion. I'm open to all solutions; I just forgot to mention one requirement in my original post: I need the names to be mapped to a zero based index. Reason is that I need to convert the names to a bitmask for my processing (1 << Index). Of course the problem could be solved differently but using a mask is the fastest solution for the specific problem.

Comment: What does it mean for names to be mapped to a zero based index. If the ids are somehow bitmasks, then surely there should not be names as keys (In other words, the "names" seem like the secondary index property)? I'm a little confused. Also, you can mix and match from all the building blocks to arrive at your desired configuration. If you get stuck doing that, let us know?

Comment: Each entry in my "container" corresponds to a layer in graphic with a specific name and I assign a mask with (1UL << index) where "index" is the index in "container". Using the map I get the index and with the index I can access the elements (payload) on that layer and I have the mask which I can use for collision detection. Does that explanation help?

Comment: I have enhanced my sample code showing the mask calculation.

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect the answer to change to improve. I really guess I've shown all the building blocks. In vector the index of an element can be calculated back (using `&element - vec.data()`) but you're right it's probably easier to the index directly instead of a reference